# Npm not working (openSSL configuration error windows10x64)

Tags: node.js, npm, openssl

I was getting this error whenever I try the npm command in powershell:

```
**~ $ node -v
v17.1.0
~ $ npm -v
OpenSSL configuration error:
74240000:error:80000003:system library:BIO_new_file:No such process:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\psqlODBC\etc\openssl.cnf, rb)
74240000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:75:
74240000:error:07000072:configuration file routines:def_load:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:179:
OpenSSL configuration error:
A8250000:error:80000003:system library:BIO_new_file:No such process:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:67:calling fopen(C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\psqlODBC\etc\openssl.cnf, rb)
A8250000:error:10000080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:75:
A8250000:error:07000072:configuration file routines:def_load:no such file:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:179:**
```

Another thing I noticed is that the node must have updated incorrectly because even though it gives me a version, I cannot uninstall it and cannot find the install files in my program files. I am at a total loss and about to just reset my computer to default. I want to repair it but everything online tells me to use npm, which in itself is not possible.

I have tried using the "set OpenSSL" command to empty or to a dummy file but it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: What command are you executing? `node -v v17.1.0` / `npm -v OpenSSL` Because they are both invalid/unassecsery. `node -v` & `npm -v` are the commands. What does `openssl version` output?

Comment: was able to fix this by installing the LTS version of node. from the site. seems the 17v has some issues on my machine.

Comment: i was using node -v and npm -v and I'm unsure about openssl version.

Answer (score 9):

Go to the Windows control panel and click on Uninstall a program, select `Node.js` and click on the uninstall tab to uninstall the node and npm successfully. Restart your system.
Then go to https://nodejs.org/en/ to download 16.13.0 LTS version and install it

Comment: yea this did not want to work for me at first, for some reason. maybe due to the last windows update but node did not want to appear in my list of uninstall-able programs, even though my cmd was able to give me the version number and take some node commands. but i do concur that installing the LTS version was much friendlier to my system than version 17.

Comment: yes, reinstalling NodeJs helped me too. I'm using NVM, so I just NVM-installed another version of Node and used it.

Comment: still relevant with nodejs version 18.5.0, a downgrade to 16.13.0 LTS worked for me.

Comment: Had the same problem with version 18.16.0 and 18.16.1. Downgrading to 16.13.0 worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Please check environment path using PowerShell

check environment path:

```
cmd /c echo %PATH%' or 'cmd /c echo %OPENSSL_CONF%
```

You will get `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\psqlODBC\etc\openssl.cnf` path so reset the environment path for `openssl` using below comment on PowerShell

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=''
```

after that, the problem will be fixed.

this issue already issued on Nodejs GitHub.
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40547

Answer (score 3):

the only thing that you're to do is to create a new archive called `openssl.cnf`
in this route:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\psqlODBC\etc\openssl.cnf
```

Save the work and run in cmd: `npm --version`

Comment: For those who got the error after installing PostgreSQL, THIS is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue in a conda environment. Fixed by installing node with next command: `conda install -c conda-forge nodejs=16.3.2`

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the node from your project directory.

`npm uninstall node`

Most probably you have 2 different versions of Node installed on your system.

If my solution does not work for you. Try the other suggestions with uninstalling Node from the system.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use another node version in this case 15.8.0, you can try with others most recently versions. When I did this npm was installed correctly:

[image]